# Клонировать на github чужой репозиторий

Tags: git, github, git-push

Клонировал чужой репозиторий на свой компьютер, работаю с этим проектом и теперь хочу запушить его на свою страницу гитхаба в новый репозиторий. 
Выбивает мне ошибку:

> **unable to access**. The requested URL returned error: 403

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Проще всего сначала форкнуть репозиторий и клонировать уже свой форк.

Comment: Если предположить, что Вы уже сделали форк (например, посредством [**`hub fork`**](https://hub.github.com/)), вероятно, Вы делаете `git push origin YourBranch` вместо `git push YourGitHubName YourBranch`. Если нет, пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос команды, которые Вы вводили в терминал. Спасибо.

Comment: git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git

Answer (score 2):

403 это ошибка - Доступ запрещен
Может вы по ошибке на чужой удаленный репозиторий отправляете?
git remote show какие репозитории показывает?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему вы клонировали чужой репозиторий, к которому вам никто не давал доступа на запись. Доступ на чтение есть у всех, так как это публичный репозиторий, по этому вы смогли его клонировать.
Вы можете выложить этот репозиторий на свой гитхаб, но тогда потеряется информация о том, что репозиторий был форкнут (ответвлен) от оригинального - это будет отдельный самостоятельный репозиторий. Обычно так делать не стоит, по этому я не буду рассматривать этот вариант более подробно.

Правильнее сделать так:

1. Через интерфейс гитхаба форкнуть [image: кнопка fork] оригинальный репозиторий. Это создаст копию репозитория в вашем аккаунте и при этом гитхаб будет знать, что он ответвлен от оригинального и это вам позволит, например, создавать в него пулл-реквесты.
2. Добавить ваш форк как удаленный репозиторий в вашем локальном репозитории. Скорее всего у вас оригинальный репозиторий назван как origin. Можно либо добавить свой с другим именем, либо изменить url у существующего. На мой взгляд, чтобы было меньше путаницы, лучше если origin будет ссылаться на основной для вас репозиторий, в который вы будете пушить (то есть ваш форк): `git remote set-url origin <адрес вашего репозитория>`. А для оригинального репозитория принято использовать имя upstream: `git remote add upstream <адрес оригинального репозитория>`